# Is there a cythonized version of `norm` methods from scipy.stats?

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I'm talking about the main public methods for continuous RV in scipy.stats:

specifically, 
`from scipy.stats import norm`
then using

`norm.ppf` or `norm.pdf`

Link: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html

Is there any opportunity for speed optimization on norm.ppf() or norm.pdf() from using cython? Or is it already optimized or not worth wrapping with cython?

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the code in

.../scipy/stats/distributions.py?

It looks like `norm_pdf` ends up using

```
_norm_pdf_C = math.sqrt(2*pi)
_norm_pdf_logC = math.log(_norm_pdf_C)

def _norm_pdf(x):
    return exp(-x**2/2.0) / _norm_pdf_C
```

Since it doesn't involve a loop through numpy arrays it does not look like a prime candidate for `cython` speedup.  Would you write it differently?

---

Opps, sorry.  You are asking about a function like:

```
def pdf(self,x,*args,**kwds):
    args, loc, scale = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)
    x,loc,scale = map(asarray,(x,loc,scale))
    args = tuple(map(asarray,args))
    x = asarray((x-loc)*1.0/scale)
    cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
    cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x >= self.a) & (x <= self.b)
    cond = cond0 & cond1
    output = zeros(shape(cond),'d')
    putmask(output,(1-cond0)+np.isnan(x),self.badvalue)
    if any(cond):
        goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))
        scale, goodargs = goodargs[-1], goodargs[:-1]
        place(output,cond,self._pdf(*goodargs) / scale)
    if output.ndim == 0:
        return output[()]
    return output
```

Besides argument checking and massaging with `map`, I see some iteration hiding in `putmask` and `place`.  I haven't used `place` much, but I think it's iterating on `cond`, and applying `self._pdf`, and placing the values in `output`.  I suspect code organization is intended to provide a lot of flexibility, allowing for different models and distributions.  I don't see tight code aimed at speed.

For code that would benefit from conversion to `cython` you probably need to write something from scratch, something that does not call alot of other `numpy` and `scipy` code, and does not build an elaborate class structure.  Focus on a very specific calculation, not a family of calculations.

Comment: The code i'm referring to is actually in scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure for scipy 0.15.1.  So the source for `from scipy.stats import norm` and then `norm.ppf()` is lines 1785-1828 from that private module.  And to your question about prime candidate, I would have used `from libc.math cimport exp, sqrt, log` which are precompiled C versions of the python builtin math